# Как создать лист в фрагменте, не создавая активность?

Tags: java, android, массивы, android-fragment, list

Из главной активности в разметке вызываю

```
 <fragment class="com.example.viktor.buyersguide.Section"
```

В `Section.java` :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    String[] nameList = new String[Cards.cards.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < Cards.cards.length; i++) {
        nameList[i] = Cards.cards[i];
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(inflater.getContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, nameList);
    setListAdapter(listAdapter);

    return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
```

Формирую список. По нажатию нужно чтобы открылся новый список с другими данными. Например,если нажали на первый элемент списка, то

```
String[] nameList = new String[Cards.app.length];

        for(int i = 0; i < Cards.app.length; i++) {
            nameList[i] = Cards.app[i];
        }
```

Как это сделать, не создавая активность, не используя интент и не вызывая с разметки активности новый класс `SubSection` (как я сделал это с разметки главной активности, вызвав `Section`), который уже будет создавать лист снова, а сделать это непосредственно из фрагмента `Section`?

Comment: Вопрос только в том, куда вы хотите этот новый список поместить. Сам по себе он не может отображаться, должен быть UI контейнер: активити, фрагмент или диалог.

Comment: так у меня в разметке главной активности <fragment> , где отображается первый список сейчас

Comment: вот и думаю, по сути нельзя заменить просто или обязательно нужно создать новую разметку/активность?